# Does anything other that upload_max_filesize and post_max_size affect total upload size?

Tags: php, nginx

My php.ini has these max values set

```
...
post_max_size = 50M
...
upload_max_filesize = 50M
...
```

When I try to upload a 1.3MB file I get a 413 error

The nginx logs Show that it's only 1.3MB

```
[error] 1306#1306: *8152 client intended to send too large body: 1325278 bytes, client: 70.36.52.77, server: my.domain.com, request: "POST /library/save HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.com", referrer: "http://my.domain.com/library/add"
```

What else could be limiting the upload size?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: The webserver has it's own setting for that. Which webserver is it? edit: I read nginx, so try this in your nginx.conf `client_max_body_size 50M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Honk der Hase has the answer that worked for me

`client_max_body_size 50M` in nginx.conf